# A field F can be extended to one in which all polynomials over F have a solution

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, field-theory

Please check to see if my methods are correct. This question is a lot to absorb all at once.

> Let P be the set of non-constant polynomials over a field F and let X be the set of finite subsets of P.
>   For each $\Delta \in X$ we can find an extension of F, $F_\Delta$ such that every polynomial in $\Delta$ has a solution in $F_\Delta$. 
>   Let $R = \prod_{\Delta \in X}F_\Delta$ and let $I = \left\{ \bar{a} \in R: \mathrm{for \;some} \; \Delta \in X, \; \mathrm{if}\; \Delta \subseteq \Sigma \in X \; \mathrm{then}\; a_\Sigma = 0 \right\}$.
>   Here, we are considering $\bar{a} \in R$ as the sequence $\left \langle a_\Sigma: \Sigma \in X \right \rangle$.
>
> Show that $I$ is a proper ideal. Choose a maximal ideal $J$ with $I \subseteq J$ and let $K = R/J$; $K$ is a field.

It's a proper ideal because the constant sequence of all $1$ is not contained in the set $I$. Every sequence in $I$ has a $0$ in the $\Sigma th$ place.

To show $I$ is an ideal, I show closure under $+$ and closure under $\cdot$. Take two elements $\bar{a} = \left \langle a_\Sigma: \Sigma \in X \right \rangle$ and $\bar{b} = \left \langle b_\Sigma: \Sigma \in X \right \rangle$.

This is where it gets a little confusing for me. There is a lot here to unravel.

Based on what $I$ is, there are $\Delta$, $\Phi \in X$ such that if $\Delta \subseteq \Sigma$ then $a_\Sigma = 0$ and also if $\Phi \subseteq \Sigma$ then $b_\Sigma = 0$.
Clearly $\Delta \cup \Phi \in X$, so then if $\Delta \cup \Phi \subseteq \Sigma$ then $a_\Sigma + b_\Sigma = 0$ so $\bar{a} + \bar{b} \in I$.

Now, let $\bar{r} = \left \langle r_\Sigma: \Sigma \in X \right \rangle$, and let $\bar{a} = \left \langle a_\Sigma: \Sigma \in X \right \rangle$. So, for some $\Delta \in X$, if $\Delta \subseteq \Sigma$ then $a_\Sigma = 0$. But then $r_\Sigma a_\Sigma = 0$ so $\bar{r}\bar{a} \in I$.

The question continues:

> Choose a maximal ideal $J$ with $I \subseteq J$ and let $K = R/J$; $K$ is a field.
>   So, since we proved that $I$ is proper, we can find that $J$ and quotient $R$ by it to create the field $K$.

Now, the next part:

> b) Let $\Phi:F \rightarrow K$ be defined by $\Phi(a) = \left \langle a: \Delta \in X \right \rangle / J$ i.e. the constant sequence $a$ modulo $J$.
>   Show that $\Phi$ is an embedding. Hence we can associate $F$ with the image of $\Phi$.

As far as I can tell, since $I$ is proper (i.e. $1 \notin I$), $I \neq J$.
So, since $F$ is a field, $\Phi$ must be an embedding.

> c) Show that $K$ satisfies all polynomials over $F$.

Let $f \in F[x]$. If $f \in \Delta$ then $f$ has a solution in $F_\Delta$.
This is all that pops out to me. Somehow, I have to show that this $f$ is solvable in $K$ but nothing comes to me.

Comment: The part beginning with "Based on what..." is a little confusing: perhaps better could be : "...there are $$\;\Delta\,,\,\Phi\in X\;\;s.t.\;\;\Delta\subset\Sigma\implies a_\Sigma=0\;,\;\;\Phi\subset \Sigma'\implies b_{\Sigma'}=0$$so clearly there exists: $$\Delta\cup\Phi\subset X\;,\;\;\text{and also}\;\;\Delta\cup\Phi\subset\Sigma''\implies\begin{cases}a_{\Sigma''}=0\;,\;\;\text{and also}\\b_{\Sigma''}=0\end{cases}$$since both $\;\Delta\,,\,\,\Phi\subset\Sigma''\;$ and thus $\;\overline a+\overline b\in I\;$

Comment: Nto that this will help (me), but I think $\;I\;$ is precisely the set of all elements in $\;R\;$ with just a *finite number of non-zero coordinates*. Anyway, I still can't see how the proof develops. Is it claimed that $\;K\;$ is the promised algebraically closed field? I know other proof(s) which, for me, are way easier. Where is this one from?

Comment: It's from course notes of a ring theory class.